# Как сделать вывод даты в формате "Сегодня, Вчера" ?

Tags: php, mysql

например есть такой код(урезан), который выводить новости, в нем есть див в котором находится дата, берется из базы данных, она выводится в формате 2014-06-26 12:45:10 а нужно так

Если опубликовано сегодня, 5 минут назад то выводить:
**5 минут назад,**

Если прошел, например, 1 час выводить:
**Сегодня в 16:10**

Если вчера, то вчера:
**Вчера в 16:10**

Если в этом году:
**26 июня в 16:10**

Если не в этом году, то:
**26 июня 2014 в 16:10**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE visible='1' ORDER BY datetime DESC",$link);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo '<div class="datetime">'.$row["datetime"].'</div>'; 
 do {
 ?>
```

**Решения**

```
$date_str = new DateTime($row["datetime"]);
$date = $date_str->Format('d.m.Y');
$date_month = $date_str->Format('d.m');
$date_year = $date_str->Format('Y');

$date_time = $date_str->Format('H:i');

 $ndate = date('d.m.Y');
 $ndate_time = date('H:i');
 $ndate_time_m = date('i');
 $ndate_exp = explode('.', $date);
 $nmonth = array(
1 => 'янв',
  2 => 'фев',
  3 => 'мар',
  4 => 'апр',
  5 => 'мая',
  6 => 'июн',
  7 => 'июл',
  8 => 'авг',
  9 => 'сен',
  10 => 'окт',
  11 => 'ноя',
  12 => 'дек'
 );

foreach ($nmonth as $key => $value) {
  if($key == intval($ndate_exp[1])) $nmonth_name = $value;
 }

if ($date == date('d.m.Y')){
$datetime = 'Cегодня в ' .$date_time;
}

else if ($date == date('d.m.Y', strtotime('-1 day'))){
$datetime = 'Вчера в ' .$date_time;
}

else if ($date != date('d.m.Y') && $date_year != date('Y')){
$datetime = $ndate_exp[0].' '.$nmonth_name.' '.$ndate_exp[2]. ' в '.$date_time;
}

else {
$datetime = $ndate_exp[0].' '.$nmonth_name.' в '.$date_time;
}
```

Comment: никак, тут программировать надо. [самостоятельно](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php).

Comment: исходя из комментария [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/331558/php-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5) - что именно не работает, какие ошибки и пр.?

Comment: @etki я не понимаю о чем вы?

Comment: @Surfer, ваш вопрос и тот, на который я ссылаюсь - идентичны с точностью до примеров и организации вывода. Плюсуя сюда дату регистрации, я делаю нехитрый вывод, что вы - @Titan93. Конкретно я ссылаюсь на комментарий "что-то не работает", который не дает никаких подробностей о том, что именно не работает.
И, тысяча чертей, не надо ставить вопросительный знак в конце утверждения.

Comment: @Etki >И, тысяча чертей, не надо ставить вопросительный знак в конце утверждения.
Так это не утверждение, надо просто "Сегодня, Завтра, Вчера" в кавычки поставить. Но это уже на русский язык(http://russ.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: @cadmy: утверждением было «я не понимаю, о чём вы». _Ваш К. О._

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT
  IF( (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)) < 600
    , IF( (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)) < 60
    , 'Только что'
    ,CONCAT(ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)) / 60), ' мин. назад')
      )
    , IF( DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')
        , DATE_FORMAT(`date`, 'Сегодня | %H:%i')
        , IF( DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')
           , DATE_FORMAT(`date`, 'Вчера | %H:%i')
           , IF( DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y')
              , DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d %M | %H:%i')
              , DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d %M %Y | %H:%i')
           )       
        )
      )
  ) AS `ourString`
FROM
  `table`
```

**`date`** - поле типа **DATETIME**

Comment: старое доброе хардкорное адище, неистово плюсую

Comment: @Etki, если БД может вернуть то, что нам надо, то что нам еще надо?)

Comment: @dekameron вы действительно думаете что за это должна отвечать БД?)

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку тут тег только PHP, то вот отличная функция:

```
function new_time($a) { // преобразовываем время в нормальный вид
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
 $ndate = date('d.m.Y', $a);
 $ndate_time = date('H:i', $a);
 $ndate_exp = explode('.', $ndate);
 $nmonth = array(
  1 => 'янв',
  2 => 'фев',
  3 => 'мар',
  4 => 'апр',
  5 => 'мая',
  6 => 'июн',
  7 => 'июл',
  8 => 'авг',
  9 => 'сен',
  10 => 'окт',
  11 => 'ноя',
  12 => 'дек'
 );

 foreach ($nmonth as $key => $value) {
  if($key == intval($ndate_exp[1])) $nmonth_name = $value;
 }

 if($ndate == date('d.m.Y')) return 'сегодня в '.$ndate_time;
 elseif($ndate == date('d.m.Y', strtotime('-1 day'))) return 'вчера в '.$ndate_time;
 else return $ndate_exp[0].' '.$nmonth_name.' '.$ndate_exp[2].' в '.$ndate_time;
}
```

Пример вызова: `new_time(time());`

Comment: у меня дата храниться в базе mysql

Comment: что мешает хранить время в базе mysql в формате Unix?

Comment: .

    $timestamp = strtotime($datetime);

Comment: @Etki это не то что мне нужно

Comment: @Surfer, а что нужно?

Comment: @Etki, я же написал выше

Comment: @Surfer, а я, в свою очередь, написал, как дату преобразовать в необходимый для ответа @Виктор Евлампьев таймстамп.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже самое, но поддерживается `Через %s минут`, `Завтра в %s`, формат дат можно переопределять через аргументы функции и учитывается часовой пояс

```
function passed(
    \DateTime $date,
    $time_format = 'H:i',
    $month_format = 'H:i d/m',
    $year_format = 'H:i d/m/Y'
) {
    $today = new \DateTime('now', $date->getTimezone());
    $yesterday = new \DateTime('-1 day', $date->getTimezone());
    $tomorrow = new \DateTime('+1 day', $date->getTimezone());
    $minutes_ago = round(($today->format('U') - $date->format('U')) / 60);
    $minutes_in = round(($date->format('U') - $today->format('U')) / 60);

    if ($minutes_ago > 0 && $minutes_ago < 60) {
        return sprintf('%s минут назад', $minutes_ago);

    } elseif ($minutes_in > 0 && $minutes_in < 60) {
        return sprintf('Через %s минут', $minutes_in);

    } elseif ($today->format('ymd') == $date->format('ymd')) {
        return sprintf('Сегодня в %s', $date->format($time_format));

    } elseif ($yesterday->format('ymd') == $date->format('ymd')) {
        return sprintf('Вчера в %s', $date->format($time_format));

    } elseif ($tomorrow->format('ymd') == $date->format('ymd')) {
        return sprintf('Завтра в %s', $date->format($time_format));

    } elseif ($today->format('Y') == $date->format('Y')) {
        return $date->format($month_format);

    } else {
        return $date->format($year_format);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучшее, что использовал для работы с датой - [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Пример использования:

```
echo Carbon::now()->subMinutes(2)->diffForHumans(); // 2 minutes ago
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
/* *** Показывает сколько прошло времени от заданого значения $a ***
 Если прошло 0...55 минут: X минут назад,
 Если сегодня: Сегодня в 17:40,
 Если вчера: Вчера в 17:40,
 Если этот год: 17:40 21/04,
 Если прошлый и менее год: 17:40 21/04/2014,
*/
function passed_time($a){
 $time = time();
 $tm = date('H:i', $a);
 $d = date('d', $a);
 $m = date('m', $a);
 $y = date('Y', $a);
 $last = round(($time - $a)/60);
 if( $last < 55 ) return "$last минут назад";
 elseif($d.$m.$y == date('dmY',$time)) return "Сегодня в $tm";
 elseif($d.$m.$y == date('dmY', strtotime('-1 day'))) return "Вчера в $tm";
 elseif($y == date('Y',$time)) return "$tm $d/$m";
 else return "$tm $d/$m/$y";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я для себя вот так делал:
В cuteDate просто передать дату, на выходе будет:

Сегодня в 16:10

Вчера в 17:45

```
 public static function cuteDate($date)
  {
    $today = date('d.m.Y', time());
    $yesterday = date('d.m.Y', time() - 86400);
    $dbDate = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($date));
    $dbTime = date('H:i', strtotime($date));

    switch ($dbDate)
    {
      case $today : $output = 'Сегодня в '. $dbTime; break;
      case $yesterday : $output = 'Вчера в '. $dbTime; break;
      default : $output = $dbDate;
    }
    return $output;
  }
```